# Yii2 authclient PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, oauth-2.0, yii2

I use Yii2 authclient for auth user.
How I can add paypal authclient class?

PayPal have OAuth2 - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authentication--headers

I use example of facebook authclient:

```
class Facebook extends OAuth2

{
    public $authUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';
    public $tokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    public $apiBaseUrl = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/';
    public $scope = 'email';

    protected function initUserAttributes()
    {
        return $this->api('identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid', 'GET');
    }

    protected function defaultName()
    {
        return 'paypal';
    }

    protected function defaultTitle()
    {
        return 'PayPal';
    }
}
```

Which url parameters can I set to $authUrl, $tokenUrl.

I test with https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token and https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice

But does not work